# Jquery colorbox and sidebars doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-plugins

We use JQuery colorbox and sidebars to make an application.
The content consists of the colorbox area and the sidebar area.
If I click a colorbox area element,the element will be copied into the sidebars area.
if I click the sidebars area element as below of HTML, the element will copied another area.
The native sidebar element will be copied without problem,but the copied element from colorbox area will not copied and label color not changed.

```
<div class="checkbox" id="additional_member">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_member" id="sidebar_member1" class="cb_member" value="155">
<label for="sidebar_member1" class="sb_member checked" id="lb_sb1">
<span id="member_name1">TEST1</span>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_member" id="sidebar_member2" class="cb_member" value="025">
<label for="sidebar_member2" class="sb_member" id="lb_sb2">
<span id="member_name2">TEST2</span>
</label>
</div>

 //sidebars
$('#additional_member').on('click', '.sb_member', function(){
    var index    =    $(".sb_member").index(this);
    var val        =    $("#sidebar_member" + ( index +1 ) ).val();
    var str        =    $("span#member_name" + ( index +1 )).html();
    //
    if($("div#additional_member label:eq(" + index  + ")").hasClass("checked")){
        //remove
        $("div#add_member input").filter(function(){
            return $(this).val() == val;
        }).remove();
        //remove from member list
        $("ul#member_list li").filter(function(){
            return $(this).text() == str;
        }).remove();
        //color turns to white(not checked)
        var j = 0;
        var pos = 0;
        $("div#additional_member input").filter(function(){
            if(val == $(this).val()){
                pos = j;
            }
            j++;
        });
        $("div#additional_member label:eq(" + pos + ")").removeClass('checked');
        return false;
    }else{
        var count_li    =    $("ul#member_list li").length;
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            class: 'member',
            id: 'member_id' + (index + 1),
            name: 'member[]',
            value: val
        }).appendTo('div#add_member');
        //
        var j = 0;
        var pos = 0;
        $("div#additional_member input").filter(function(){
            if(val == $(this).val()){
                pos = j;
            }
            j++;
        });
        $("div#additional_member label:eq(" + pos + ")").addClass('checked');
        //string for assigned member section
        var str_li = '<li id="list_elm' + (count_li + 1) + '">' + str + '</li>';
        //data for POST
        var j    =    0;
        $("div#add_member input").filter(function(){
            if(val == $(this).val()){
                j++;
            }
        });
        //member list
        var j    =    0;
        $("ul#member_list li").filter(function(){
            if(str == $(this).text()){
                j++;
            }
        });
        //append
        if(j == 0){
            $('ul#member_list').append(str_li);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

part of `if($("div#additional_member label:eq("+index+")").hasClass("checked")){`

doesn't work.
This part treated twice.I can't understand the reason.

Please tell me!!

Comment: This looks like a simple syntax error to me... what does the console say?

Comment: Console says nothing.Do you think which part wrong is?

Comment: Can you recreate the same thing as a [code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/)? I may be missing something but `$("div#additional_member label:eq(" + pos + ")")` doesnt look like a valid selector. It should throw a console error.